# Sync between PC & External Harddisk

Tags: windows, file-synchronization, portable, hard-disk

I've recently bought an External Harddisk, and I haven't even finished opening the package yet. Although, I'll be connecting it to my PC later this week, I needed to know if I could sync my files and folders to this harddisk. A way to sync all files and folders to my external harddisk.

I'm trying to look for a good app, that lets me select the changes being made to my synced backup. For example, when I move a music album folder to a different directory, and later start the sync when connected-via-usb, then **this app could let me select what changes I'd like to update to my external harddisk, and what changes to be ignored?** In this case, it should show that the location of the folder has changed. Maybe keeping an *MD5* on all files and tracking those files and folders that way, I'm not sure, dropbox does something like this, therefore I was wondering if there's a offline portable app that I could keep on my external harddisk, and sync easily!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/) is the one tool you are looking for:

- [Analysis](https://sites.google.com/site/synkrondocumentation/documentation-1-5#TOC-Analysis)
- portable
- and cross-platform ([Windows, Mac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synkron/files/synkron/1.6.2/) & [Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synkron/files/synkron%20%28Linux%20builds%29/1.6.0/))

---

since Synkron is no more developed, maybe try [DirSync Pro](http://www.dirsyncpro.org/)... it seems to also have a [analysis tool](http://directorysync.sourceforge.net/images/main02.png).

and also [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org/) seems to have something like a [comparison/analysis-tool](https://www.freefilesync.org/images/screenshots/binary.png).

Comment: Thanks! I knew about Synkron, although didn't know I could compare two folders before the sync too! I'll try FreeFileSync too! It had max points on [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/synkron/) website...